# How to manually drag and adjust image until it fit in the specific box in css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to ask that how to manually drag an image and adjust an image to specific box in CSS? For example, in CMS like website if someone browse and upload his/her profile image, then he/she is able to adjust his/her image in that box or frame.
I also want such type of functionality in css. So, how could to do this in css or css3?

Comment: I think you need JS for that. I am sure there are existing picture upload libraries for that.

Answer (score 0):

You COULD do the clipping in css (see clipping: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/)

But really, you want to use JS. Remember: CSS = presentation, JS = interaction. If you want user interaction, you want JS. Since the size & offset of the clip is based on user input, you'll need at least a little JS to pass the user input to change the CSS.

Comment: O.K. Its helpful. I really don't know about clipping and mask before.